# Get session id from a session cookie in classic ASP

Tags: session, asp-classic

I'm attempting to share session data between my PHP site and an ASP site and as I have access to the ASP site's MSSQL database and some of the ASP session data appears to be in a database table I was hoping I could grab the session id from the session cookie and go from there.
I don't know a lot about ASP but from what I've read it takes the session id, encrypts it and produces a session cookie name / value. Does anyone know how I can decrypt that cookie and get the session id back?

Or is there a better way of doing this baring in mind although I have database access I'm not really able to make code changes.

Comment: even if you made it possible to decrypt the session id from the asp session cookie how would you access that cooike from php? as you have two sites the cookies of the asp site are not available in the php site?

Comment: the ASP site is on a subdomain of the domain the php site is on so it should be possible to change the ASP cookie domain so it's readable on the php site.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the sessionID via the Session object

```
<%
Response.Write(Session.SessionID)
%>
```

Note though that the session ID is only valid for a user's current session and is not persistent. i.e. if there's no activity for 20min a new session is created for the user if they return. I'd use regular cookies myself and pass a hash around.